# What inspired the title of "Why Didn't They Ask Evans?"?

Tags: inspiration, title, agatha-christie, why-didnt-they-ask-evans

[*Why Didn't They Ask Evans?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_Didn%27t_They_Ask_Evans%3F) is a novel by Agatha Christie. In the story, a dying man's last words "Why didn't they ask Evans?" inspires an amateur detective investigation, in which ultimately

> "Evans" turns out to be a parlourmaid, Gladys Evans, and the fact that she was *not* asked to witness a will turns out to be significant.

I was told once that the title of this story was inspired by a phrase Agatha Christie overheard, "why didn't they ask Evans?", and she decided to write a story with this title. But I don't know if this is true or not, and couldn't find this claim online.

**What, if anything, inspired the title of this novel?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm wondering if the claim you heard was a conflation of a few things.

I could find two sources online stating that the title of *Why Didn't They Ask Evans* was something Christie overheard. The first is [this IMDB review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2801173/?ref_=tt_urv) from 2013, which claims:

> The title of the book actually came from a conversation Ms. Christie
> overheard coming out of a movie theater, and she built a whole story
> around it.

The second is [this blog post](https://thombeckett.com/blog/why-didnt-they-ask-evans-by-agatha-christie):

> In her autobiography, Agatha Christie talks about how she comes by
> ideas for various books. This one started with the title, which was a
> phrase she overheard.

I've read the autobiography, and have it on Kindle. I searched every variation of "ask", "asked", "question", "overheard", "Evans", "theatre", "title" and etc that I could think of and didn't find any reference to this particular novel or inspirations for it.

There is, however, a reference in the autobiography to one piece of inspiration Christie did get from overhearing a conversation:

> I considered writing another book. Supposing I did--what should it be
> about?
>
> The question was solved for me one day when I was having tea in an
> ABC. Two people were talking at a table nearby, discussing somebody
> called Jane Fish. It struck me as a most entertaining name. I went
> away with the name in my mind. Jane Fish. That, I thought, would make
> a good beginning to a story--a name overheard at a tea shop--an
> unusual name, so that whoever heard it remembered it. A name like Jane
> Fish--or perhaps Jane Finn would be even better.

This became *The Secret Adversary* (1922):

> “Funny scraps one does overhear,” murmured Tommy. “I passed two
> Johnnies in the street to-day talking about some one called Jane Finn.
> Did you ever hear such a name?”

As for the movie theater, take a look at this quote from Christie's *Lord Edgware Dies* (published a year before *Why Didn't They Ask Evans*):

> **We were passing a big cinema.** People were streaming out of it
> discussing their own affairs, their servants, their friends of the
> opposite sex, and just occasionally, the picture they had just seen.
>
> With a group of them we crossed the Euston Road.
>
> ‘I loved it,’ a girl was sighing. ‘I think Bryan Martin’s just
> wonderful. I never miss any picture he’s in. The way he rode down the
> cliff and got there in time with the papers.’
>
> Her escort was less enthusiastic.
>
> ‘Idiotic story. **If they’d just had the sense to ask Ellis right away.**
> Which anyone worth sense would have done—’

This is clearly someone overhearing a phrase, where the speaker is wondering why someone whose name begins with E wasn't asked--while coming out of a movie theater. However, the difference is that the overhear-ers here are Poirot and Hastings, not Christie herself.

It's certainly possible that Christie reused the phrasing from *Lord Edgware Dies* in *Why Didn't They Ask Evans*. However, I can find no evidence that she herself ever overheard this specific phrase.

Comment: Great sleuthing, thank you. It's interesting that you found two sources making the same claim that I remember, suggesting that it's either a reasonably common urban myth, or actually true but very hard to substantiate. Anyway, unless someone finds a definitive proof of the claim, this answer seems as good as we're going to get.

Comment: What's so unusual about the name "Jane Finn"? Especially when compared to "Jane Fish"?